# A question about Morophon, the Boundless

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The question is simple if an effect caused [Morophon, the Boundless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMorophon%2c%20the%20Boundless%5d)' enter the battlefield effect, "As Morophon, the Boundless enters the battlefield, choose a creature type.", to trigger twice would the second choice replace the first choice? Or would they both stick?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? A card like [Flicker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15127)?

Comment: I was actually thinking of Yarok, the Desecrated, from the new Core Set, it has "If a permanent entering the battlefield causes the triggered ability of a permanent you control to trigger, that ability triggers an additional time." as entering the battlefield is a triggered ability of Morophon it should trigger twice if Yarok is play and under your control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Morophon, the Boundless' second ability is a replacement effect:

> 614.1c Effects that read “[This permanent] enters the battlefield with . . . ,” “As [this permanent] enters the battlefield . . . ,” or “[This permanent] enters the battlefield as . . . “ are replacement effects.

Replacement effects don't 'trigger' and AFAIK there is no way with the current Magic cards to make them apply twice. [Yarok, the Desecrated](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bYarok%2c%20the%20Desecrated%5d) only duplicates triggered abilities, not replacement effects. One of the rulings below the card in Gatherer mentions this as well:

> Abilities that apply “as [this creature] enters the battlefield,” such as choosing a color with Diamond Knight, are also unaffected.